# Launch instagram app from phonegap android app

Tags: android, cordova, instagram

I have a phonegap built android app made of html5 and javascript, i want to launch instagram app onclcik of a button.How is it possible without writing code in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin for that. Check out this link: https://github.com/dmedvinsky/cordova-startapp.

Add it to your project, then simply call

```
window.startapp.start(
    {
        android: com.instagram.android',
        ios: 'instagramURL'
    },
    successCallback, failureCallback
);
```

(you need to change the ios-url and the callbacks)

Comment: the above .js is not functioning suddenly.
it is always going to the failiure even though  the application is present